# Binary String Combinations

Tags: binary

For this question, imagine finite binary strings consisting of $0$ and $1$.
For instance, $00111$ is a string.  Order does not matter, so the string $1100$ is
considered equivalent to $0011$.  We will therefore always write $0$s before writing $1$s.
For ease of notation, we will write $0^{n}$ when
we mean exaclty $n$ zeros.  Therefore,
$0^{4}1^{2}=000011$.  These exponents do
not indicate multiplication!

Here are three rules for manipulating a string:

Rule 1:  You may always replace a $1$ with $11$. We will write this as $1 \stackrel{1}{\rightarrow} 11$.

Rule 2: You may replace $11$ with a $0$.  More succinctly,
$11 \stackrel{2}{\rightarrow} 0$.

Rule 3:  You may erase $00$.  We can write this as
$00 \stackrel{3}{\rightarrow} \mbox{ null}$.

The following sequence is legal:
$0^41^{2}=\underline{\bf 00}0011 \stackrel{3}{\rightarrow} \underline{\bf 00}11 \stackrel{3}{\rightarrow}
\underline{\bf 11} \stackrel{2}{\rightarrow} 0. $

Therefore, the string $0^{4}1^{2}$ has been transformed into the string $0$, and
we can write $0^{4}1^{2} \rightarrow 0$.  For any bean counters out there, we used Rule 2 once
and Rule 3 twice.  We did not use Rule 1 at all.  Note that, for clarity, we have boldfaced
and underlined the characters that are being operated on.

1. Prove or disprove
   $0^{3}1^{3} \rightarrow {\tt null}$.
2. Let $0^{n}1^{n}$ denote a string with $n$ zeros
   followed by $n$ ones.  Prove or disprove $0^{n}1^{n} 
   \rightarrow {null}$.
3. What can you say about $0^{m}1^{n}$?

Comment: $0^{3}1^{3} \rightarrow {\tt null}$ I guess that means that there exists some rules combination that produces that output ? If so, have you tried to find it?

You might get answers here if you show some effort.

Comment: Yes I found a way to get it to null 000111 --> 0111 --> 0111111 --> 0000 --> null

Comment: HINT: Every string $0^m1^n$ can be reduced either to the null string or to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can you say about combining rule 1 and 2 ?

> It flips ones into zeroes, indeed $1\to 11\to 0$

So what does it do to $1^n$ ?

> prove by induction $1^n\to 0^n$

What does rule 3 applied repeatedly do to a string of only zeroes ?

> it removes any pair of zeroes, so $0^{2p}\to\tt{null}$ and $0^{2p+1}\to 0$

Can you modify the number of $1$ ?

> Yes notice that by rule 1 we can append as many additional $1$ as wanted, in particular if $n>0$ (if there is at least one $1$) then $1^n\to 1^{n+1}$

Conclude

> $0^m1^n\to 0^m0^n=0^{m+n}\to 0\text{ or }\tt{null }$ depending on the parity of $m+n$, but since we can turn $m+n$ even by appending some $1$ then we are always able to eventually land on $\tt{null}$.